# apply function by name of list

Tags: r, lapply

Imagine that I have a list

```
l <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
```

and a data frame

```
id   value
 a       3
 b       4
```

I want to match id with list names, and apply a function on that list with the value in data frame. For example, I want the sum of value in the data frame and corresponding value in the list, I get

```
 id   value 
  a    4
  b    6
```

Anyone has a clue?

Edit:
A.
I just want to expand the question a little bit with. Now, I have more than one value in every elements of list.

```
l <- list("a" = c(1, 2), "b" =c(1, 2))
```

I still want the sum

```
  id   value 
   a     6
   b     7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `match` the `names` of the `list` with `id` of dataframe, `unlist` the `list` accordingly and add it to `value`

```
df$value <- unlist(l[match(df$id, names(l))]) + df$value

df
#  id value
#1  a     4
#2  b     6
```

**EDIT**

If we have multiple entries in list we need to `sum` every list after matching. We can do

```
df$value <- df$value + sapply(l[match(df$id, names(l))], sum)
df

#  id value
#1  a     6
#2  b     7
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need

```
df$value=df$value+unlist(l)[df$id]# vector have names can just order by names 
df
  id value
1  a     4
2  b     6
```

Try answer with Ronak

```
l <- list("b" = 2, "a" = 1)

unlist(l)[as.character(df$id)]# if you id in df is factor 
a b 
1 2
```

Update

```
df$value=df$value+unlist(lapply(l,sum))[df$id]
```

Comment: @RonakShah no worry :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong - i've just had a brain-snap. It's Friday afternoon and I'm clearly not thinking straight any longer :-)

Comment: @thelatemail got u , thanks a lot . :-) it is midnight for me feel the same .Zzzz